# Scala/Java BsonDocument append not working properly

Tags: java, mongodb, scala, bson

I am new to scala and I am trying to create a custom BsonDocument. As far as I read in the documentation [here](http://api.mongodb.com/java/3.2/), there's this method `append(String key, BsonValue value)` that calls the `put` method internally and I am trying to use it.

The problem is that when I append more than two fields, only the last two get appended. For example if I have a code like this:

```
var doc = new BsonDocument();
val mapAccounts = user.accounts.map(e => new BsonString(e))    
doc.append("$set", new BsonDocument("userName", new BsonString(user.userName)))
.append("$set", new BsonDocument("color", new BsonString(user.color)))
.append("$addToSet", new BsonDocument("accounts", new BsonDocument("$each", new BsonArray(mapAccounts.toList.asJava))))

println(s"The Bson user is $doc")
```

In this case, I get an output like:

```
The Bson user is { "$set" : { "color" : "teal" }, "$addToSet" : { "accounts" : { "$each" : ["1"] } } }
```

As you can see, the userName is not being appended. And it repeats for the last two appended elements if I change the order.

I already tried to use `put` directly but still got the same result. Also tried to append individually like `doc = doc.append(...)` and still the same.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have two `$set` (a BSONDocument is basically a key-value mapping, and appending the same key again just resets it, in the same way a `Map.put` would).

What you want is

```
"$set" : { 
   "color" : "teal",
   "username": "Jim"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `$set` key with both values as the `BsonDocument` is backed by `Map`.

```
 doc.append("$set", new BsonDocument("userName", new BsonString(user.userName)).append("color", new BsonString(user.color)))
                .append("$addToSet", new BsonDocument("accounts", new BsonDocument("$each", new BsonArray(mapAccounts.toList.asJava))))
```